# systemctl status mariadb.service

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**i know that vendor preset: disabled is fine**

**i have changer the chown for mysql directory**
 **even the chown for  mysql.sock  changed it  three times**

**and still getting the same error**

**So any help will be thankful even if you are new**

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3 database server
        Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
                └─tokudb.conf
        Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-01-31 00:04:01 EET; 2min 39s ago
          Docs: man:mysqld(8)
                https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
       Process: 1121 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
       Process: 1038 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)


 Jan 31 00:03:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3 database server...
 Jan 31 00:04:01 localhost.localdomain mysql-prepare-db-dir[1121]: The log file /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log cannot be written, please, fix its permissions.
 Jan 31 00:04:01 localhost.localdomain mysql-prepare-db-dir[1121]: The daemon will be run under mysql:mysql
 Jan 31 00:04:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
 Jan 31 00:04:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Jan 31 00:04:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3 database server.
```

So any help will be thankful  even if you are new .

Comment: Check permissions for `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log` or just delete the file.

Comment: In addition to the above, what permissions/ownership is on /var/log/mariadb? What distro is this? Given service files differ per distro can you include `systemctl show mariadb.service`.  `journalctl -u mariadb.service` would also be a little more detailed log.

Comment: this was fedora 29    but  now i installed a fresh install of Ubuntu18 and i's working fine this is a temporary solution until i get enough time

Comment: sorry for wasting your time Mr.dan